# How can I get the average days between timestamps in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, data-science

I have Transaction data with timestamps between invoices for customers. I'm trying to calcualte the average days between two unique invoices(by 'ServicedOn').Two caveats for these are:

- A unique invoice can have multiple rows with different timestamps(as they may be serviced on at different times).
- The timestamp has time values as well, so I'm unable to use diff() method to calculate the delta days.

The dataframe looks as such:

```
InvoiceNo SoldOn    ServicedOn  ItemType    ItemCode    GuestId FinalSalePrice  FirstVisit  Package BUName  SalePrice   Merchant_id
21312   4/26/2015 12:55:12 PM   4/26/2015 8:00:00 AM    0   SER-310-008 5a531810-9413-4091-acd5-424d125b0c9e    3089.9  No  No Package  Spa 2500    POW
31639   1153    6/12/2015 7:11:22 PM    6/12/2015 6:15:00 PM    0   SER-1257-008    5a531810-9413-4091-acd5-424d125b0c9e    5700.0  No  No Package  Spa 5000    POW
42492   73  5/15/2015 8:05:50 PM    5/15/2015 8:05:50 PM    2   ITM-3407-001    5a531810-9413-4091-acd5-424d125b0c9e    1600.0  No  No Package  Default 1422    POW
42493   73  5/15/2015 8:06:08 PM    5/15/2015 8:06:08 PM    2   ITM-3175-001    5a531810-9413-4091-acd5-424d125b0c9e    2750.0  No  No Package  Default 2444    POW
42494   73  5/15/2015 8:05:38 PM    5/15/2015 8:05:38 PM    2   ITM-4340-001    5a531810-9413-4091-acd5-424d125b0c9e    575.0   No  No Package  Default 511 POW
```

I'm unsure on how to proceed, so any guidance would be apprecaited!

Comment: To clarify what you are asking, please provide what you think the results ought to be considering your sample data.

Comment: Ideally for each unique invoice, I would look at the first ServicedOn timestamp and calculate the days until the next invoiceno.'s first ServicedOn timestamp.

Comment: For Ex: at invoice no. 21312  I would look at the first servicedOn(4/26/2015) and calculate the days until invoice no. 31639's first servicedON(6/12/2015).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you want over all invoice numbers is pretty easy. If the first ServicedOn is what you're going on, you can sort, then use `groupby` and `head` to get the first date for every InvoiceNo, then select the column and calculate the mean difference:

```
mean_difference = (df.sort_values(by='ServicedOn')  # Get everything in date order
                     .groupby('InvoiceNo')  # group by invoice
                     .head(1)  # take first of each group
                     .ServicedOn  # only look at ServicedOn value
                     .diff()  # take differences
                     .mean())  # calculate mean
```

Comment: One big issue is that pandas isnt calculating the difference for the ServicedOn column and throwing unsupported operand error "str".

Comment: That means your ServicedOn column has not been parsed as a datetime.

Comment: When I input the transaction data, shall I make the serviced on exclusively a datetime column ? Thanks!

Comment: You have two options. If you are reading this data from for instance a CSV file you can use the `parse_dates` option to `read_csv` to parse the date when you read it. If you have it in another form for some reason, you can re-parse the column with `df.ServicedOn = pandas.to_datetime(df.ServicedOn)`